# How to remove preloader after polymer WebComponentsReady loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer, web-component, polymer-starter-kit

I'm using polymer starter kit 1.3 as a base of my site and I want to remove loader div after body is loaded.

My code structure looks like this:
(notice the "async" and "unresolved" attributes)

```
<head>
...
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
...
<link rel="import" id="bundle" href="/elements/elements.html" async>
...
</head>

    <body>    

          <div id="loader-wrapper" async">
            <div id="loader"></div>
          </div>

          <style async>
            ...
          </style>


       <template unresolved>
         ....
       </template>

       <script src="scripts/app.js" async></script>
    </body>
```

My app.js has

```
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
    // imports are loaded and elements have been registered
     ...

  });
```

I tried

```
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
    // imports are loaded and elements have been registered
     $('#loader-wrapper').remove();

  });
```

and of course it didn't work, because it's the only thing I found on google, and my js knowledge level is about zero.

The spinner loading instantly so I guess async attributes are about at the places they should be, but the loader stay there after page is loaded.

So, as far as I figured this is the code that listen for **"something" unresolved** to load and then it can remove that "loader-wrapper" div

The question is what code should I put there instead of "..." in that app.js code in order for that to happen ? Do I do anything wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have tried to use is jQuery. Most likely you are not importing jQuery in  your index and most likely you shouldn't. What you want to use is the native window/document functions to remove the div.

What we need to do is get the element. In this case with id as the element has id. After that we can remove it.

```
var loaderWrapper = document.getElementById('loader-wrapper');
loaderWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(loaderWrapper);
```

That will remove the div. We need to use the `x.parentNode.removeChild(x)` method as only way to remove something from the dom with native functions is to remove it through the parent.

I would suggest that you read the following articles and implement your async element loading from that base. You will most likely need to change some things here and there but with time and if you are willing to learn you will succeed.

Articles:

- https://aerotwist.com/blog/polymer-for-the-performance-obsessed/
- https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/polymer-perf.md
- https://gist.github.com/ebidel/1ba71473d687d0567bd3

Answer (score 0):

As a good person @Snekw suggested above, I was able to solve the problem, here's all the code down bellow.

If anybody else facing the same problem it might help you as well.

This is how the structure of the page should look like (the page that you want to has the spinner loader on)

(notice all the async and unresolved attributes)

```
<head>
...
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
...
<link rel="import" id="bundle" href="/elements/elements.html">
...
</head>

    <body>    

          <div id="loader-wrapper" async">
            <div id="loader"></div>
          </div>

          <style async>
            ...
          </style>


       <template unresolved>
         .... 
       </template>

       <script src="scripts/app.js" async></script>
    </body>
```

Then open your app.js file *(polymer starter kit advanced has this by default in /app/scripts/)*

and find this:

```
  // See https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1381
  window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
     // imports are loaded and elements have been registered
     ...

  });
```

then simply add the code that @Snekw suggested, so it would look like this

```
  // See https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1381
  window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
    // imports are loaded and elements have been registered

     var loaderWrapper = document.getElementById('loader-wrapper');
     loaderWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(loaderWrapper);
  });
```

Make sure what name your loader div has, if it's not loader-wrapper, don't forget to change the name in jquery code above, as well.

If you don't know how to create the spinner loader animation itself, just use this code down bellow

```
<div id="loader-wrapper" async style="z-index: -100; ">
    <div id="loader"></div>
</div>

  <style async>
#loader-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#loader {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #3498db;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}

#loader:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #e74c3c;
    -webkit-animation: spin 3s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
      animation: spin 3s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}

#loader:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #f9c922;
    -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
      animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0%   {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* IE 9 */
        transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* IE 9 */
        transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    0%   {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* IE 9 */
        transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* IE 9 */
        transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    }
}


  </style>
```

put it there instead of

this

```
          <div id="loader-wrapper" async">
            <div id="loader"></div>
          </div>

          <style async>
            ...
          </style>
```

**UPD: IMPORTANT NOTE**

It works perfectly and smooth in Firefox, because it taking its time nicely showing 1-3 seconds of smooth animation and then smoothly showing the page of the main content

However, if you have a very lightweight page and you open it in Chromium like browsers then the page will load much faster then in Firefox (probably it's because Firefox loading polyfills as well) and animation barely shows which might cause some glitches because your page loading so quickly.

To resolve this I used animate.css (https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) and wrapped the whole template with

`<div  class="animated fadeIn">
<template....
...
</div>`

And then changed

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
```

to

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-duration: 3s;
```

in animate.css

then imported

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../styles/animate.css">
```

to elements.html

Do some smarter things if you want, I'm not aware of any other since I'm new to web development, maybe someone else will add some ideas here

Comment: I thought I would comment on this as I have been plating with polymer and splash screens the past couple of days.
I have been using [this](https://aerotwist.com/blog/polymer-for-the-performance-obsessed/) and [this](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/polymer-perf.md) as well as vulcanize to effectively get the splash screen displaying instantly and then loading the webcomponents.js and elements.html after.
Just thought it may help you. :)

Comment: Thank you, those are good resources you found, I tried it now and it works too. Thanks!